# Google Map's "Only displaying top left tile", using gMaps.js in Angular JS

Tags: google-maps, angularjs

I checked that there are checkresize() methods from google Map's native API.. but it doesn't seem to work with the refresh function from gmaps.js.

Does anyone has similar problems using AngularJS and gMaps.js? How do you come to solve it?

[image: Before resize]

After i resize the window, the map appears again. So I am thinking is there anyway to check resize on initialization for gMap.js?

[image: After resize]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `ng-cloak` property on your map element or on your directive element.

"The ngCloak directive is used to prevent the Angular html template from being briefly displayed by the browser"

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngCloak

Answer (score 10):

ng-cloak did not work for me when I tried it. I think this was because I am using the map in a panel which expands on user interaction instead of being visible on load.

I switched my ng-show to an ng-if and it worked correctly. This is because the map code(I used a [directive](http://jsfiddle.net/wB7Hc/)) will not run until the if condition is true, which allows it to render properly.

*Sorry the fiddle got deleted. I don't remember what I had in it, but it was something like this
`<gmap unique="231" center="{{getAddress(item)}}" destination="{{getAddress(item)}}" origin="{{getMyAddress(item)}}" type="roadmap" marker-content="Hello"></gmap>`

The important thing is that the google scripts don't start doing their thing until your container element is actually displayed. This is accomplished with the ng-if.

Comment: It's working but only the first time the map is loaded. If I open the map, it's ok, all the tiles are displays. But if I close and open back the map only the top left tile is showed.

Comment: Also helped me. I have a directive that shows a hidden map.  Also sped up my page.

Comment: This must be the real answer,Thanks @Gray you save me a lot of time!!

Comment: Jsfiddle got 404. Can you post the important parts to keep in mind?

Comment: @Wirwing I forget what was in the fiddle. The important part is not to show/hide the map with ng-show, but use ng-if instead. You may be using a directive like `<gmap origin="{{originAddress}}" type="roadmap"></gmap>`

Answer (score 0):

map rendered successfully without resize.

Why resize gives you proper map ?

Because browser paints the view again.

How to fix it?

To get a proper layout of the map in any panel which is triggered lately, map has to be painted after the panel is loaded.This can be achieved by (setTimeout) code as mentioned below.
code objective is to trigger map resize event after 60 milli seconds.

```
setTimeout(function () {
        uiGmapIsReady.promise().then(function (maps) {
            google.maps.event.trigger(maps[0].map, 'resize');
            lat = -37;
            lon = 144;
            maps[0].map.panTo(new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lon));
            var marker = {
                id: Date.now(),
                coords: {
                    latitude: lat,
                    longitude: lon
                }
            };
            $scope.map.markers = [];
            $scope.map.markers.push(marker);
            console.log($scope.map.markers);
        });
    }, 60);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to resize the map using this code in the controller:

```
        NgMap.getMap().then(function(map){
            google.maps.event.addListener(map, "idle", function(){
                google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize'); 
            });
        });
```